# Show γ(t) = (a cos(t), a sin(t), t) is a geodesic of the cylinder .

Tags: geometry, geodesic

The first part of this question required me to compute the general geodesic of a surface of revolution. And I obtained a general equation using Christoffel's symbols.

The second part asked me to find use the first part to find the geodesic of a cylinder and I obtained that:

$$u''(t)=0$$$$
v''(t)=0$$

and then the third part is the question above. I believe that the aim here is to use what I obtained $(u''(t)=v''(t)=0)$.
But to me this makes 
$$u(t)=a+bt \text{ and } v(t)=c+dt $$

so I aim slightly confused as to how straight lines would take that form.

I apologise if this is a duplicate, I did make sure to search beforehand but I could not find one. Furthemore, please be kind.

Comment: What are your $u(t)$ and $v(t)$?

Comment: well, I don't know. 
I was given a general surface of revolution
$\phi(u,v) = (f(u)cos(v),f(u)sin(v),g(u))$ and I used the christoffel's symbols to get the above.

Comment: What about $f$ and $g$? Any function would do to get a geodesic?

Comment: Originally, there were arbitrary and then when you substitute the equation of a cylinder. It becomes $\phi(u,v)=(cos(u),sin(u),v))$

which means that all the Christoffel's symbols are zero and we only obtain: $u''(t)=0 $ and $v''(t)=0 $.

I'm a bit confused by what you mean that any function would do to get a geodesic? I'm trying to show that the geodesic is not just a straight line.

Comment: Then the particular solution $u=v=t$ gives the required result.

Comment: How?
I don't understand how setting them to be equal would give me that result, you'll just give me a straight line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equation of the geodesic is given by $\phi(u,v)=(a\cos u,a\sin u, v)$ after you substitute $u=v=t$:
$$
\gamma(t)=\phi(u(t),v(t))=(a\cos t,a\sin t, t).
$$

Comment: If that's the geodesic equation, how can it be also a straight line?
As in the geodesics of a cylinder are straight lines, circles and helices. 
How do I show a general a equation that satisfied all three?

Comment: You get a straight line with $u=k$ (constant) and $v=t$.